# Transpose in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following code shown below.

I don’t get why you need to transpose the matrix.

Could someone explain why a transpose is needed here ?

[image]

Code:

```
function b = back_and_forth(n)
    b = reshape([1:1:n^2],[n,n])’
    b([2:2:n], : ) = b([2:2:n],[end:-1:1])
end
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the code into your question, rather than the screen shot. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/7328782

Comment: You are using an accent `’` rather than an inverted comma `'` to transpose data. It is just the wrong command ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Transposing and Complex Transposing Conventions

It is due to how `reshape()` shapes the vector. In this case `reshape()` reshapes the 1-by-16 vector into a 4-by-4 array by traversing column-wise. In this case, you must take the transpose `.'` or `'` complex-conjugate transpose to make each column effectively be a row, similar to rotating the matrix. Visually:

### Test Script:

```
n = 4;    
b = reshape([1:1:n^2],[n,n]);
b
b'
b = b';

b([2:2:n],:) = b([2:2:n],[end:-1:1]);
```

### Before Transposing → `b`:

[image]

### After Complex-Conjugate Transposing → `b'`:

[image]

---

### Extension:

For complex numbers `'` does more than transposing. It also takes the complex conjugate.

**Code Snippet: Taking the complex-conjugate and transposing**

```
Complex_Number = 5 + 2i;
Complex_Number'
```

**Returns:**

> ans =
>
> 5.0000 - 2.0000i

---

**Code Snippet: Taking the transpose**

```
Complex_Number = 5 + 2i;
Complex_Number.'
```

**Returns:**

> ans =
>
> 5.0000 + 2.0000i

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**